# System of coupled differential equations of complex functions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Given a set of differential equations

$\frac{dZ_1}{dt} = a_1 Z_1 + b_1 Z_2 + c_1 Z_3 + d_1 Z_4 \\ \frac{dZ_2}{dt} = a_2 Z_1 + b_2 Z_2 + c_2 Z_3 + d_2 Z_4 \\ \frac{dZ_3}{dt} = a_3 Z_1 + b_3 Z_2 + c_3 Z_3 + d_3 Z_4 \\ \frac{dZ_1}{dt} = a_4 Z_1 + b_4 Z_2 + c_4 Z_3 + d_4 Z_4$

Here $Z_1(t), Z_2(t), Z_3(t),~ and ~Z_4(t)$ are complex functions of real variable $t$ and all the coefficients ($a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$, $d_i$) are real. How to solve this system in most efficient way without any approximations?

Comment: Let
$$Z(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
Z_{1}(t) \\
Z_{2}(t) \\
Z_{3}(t) \\
Z_{4}(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} & b_{1} & c_{1} & d_{1} \\
a_{2} & b_{2} & c_{2} & d_{2} \\
a_{3} & b_{3} & c_{3} & d_{3} \\
a_{4} & b_{4} & c_{4} & d_{4}
\end{bmatrix}$$
The equation is then
$$\frac{dZ(t)}{dt}=MZ(t)$$
Given an initial condition
$$Z(t_{0})=Z_{0}$$
The solution is
$$Z(t)=\exp\Big(M(t-t_{0})\Big)Z_{0}$$

Comment: This does work for the case when Z is real. Are you sure that it works even when Z is complex?